# Stateful recursion for building a list in a tuple

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tuples

I've put together the sample code below to demonstrate my question: What is a recursive way to build a list in a tuple?

I want to alter `recommendNPages` so that it calls `recommendPage` recursively to return `([Post], Blog)` instead of utilizing `Blog`'s data constructor.

```
data Tag = Food | Tech | Business | Travel | None
          deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum)

data Author = Joe | Bob | Kayla | Jade
          deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum)

data Post = Post{getRank::Tag,getAuthor::Author}
        deriving (Eq,Ord)

instance Show Post where
    show (Post t a) = "Tag: " ++ (show t) ++ " - " ++ "Author: "++ (show a)


newtype Blog = Blog [Post]

instance Show Blog where
    show (Blog posts) = "This blog has " ++ (show (length posts)) ++" posts"


fullBlog :: Blog
fullBlog = Blog [Post t a | a <- [Joe .. Jade],
                            t <- [Food .. None]]

recommendPage :: Blog -> (Post,Blog)
recommendPage (Blog posts) = (head posts,Blog (tail posts))


recommendNPages :: Int -> Blog -> ([Post], Blog)
recommendNPages n (Blog posts) = (take n posts, Blog $ drop n posts)
```

Any suggestions or links to documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `recommendPage` function is broken, it does not work on an empty blog. Avoid `head` and `tail`. You'll need to re-think that before we can continue working on `recommendNPages`.

Comment: You might want to read up on the `State` monad.

Comment: @Bergi, yes, an exception would be thrown. I'm thinking a recursive solution using recommendNPages would have a base case for when the Blog contains one post, in which case an empty blog would be ignored.

Comment: @SevanGolnazarian But how would you know that the blog contains exactly one post without using the `Blog` constructor? Really, your current implementation of `recommendNPages` is totally fine (maybe replace `take`+`drop` by `span`), there's no reason to use recursion here so it's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `splitAt` not `span`

Comment: `go n where go 0 x = ([], x); go n b = let (x, b') = recommendPage b in first (x:) $ go (n-1) b'` but as others mention, `recommendPage` is partial so this isn't the best

Comment: I appreciate the input. @moonGoose I submitted an answer based on your feedback. @Bergi, I've ignored the issue with `recommendPage` because my goal was to build `([Post], Blog)` recursively while avoiding `Blog`'s data constructor - moonGoose's approach does this. Feel free to pick apart the code if you have the time. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Sorry for doubling down on this point, but why do you want to avoid using the `Blog` constructor? Like Bergi, I think your original `recommendNPages` is just fine (you might use `splitAt` and then `second` to apply the constructor instead of `take` and `drop`, but that's secondary).

Comment: @duplode No worries! I came across a module that exported a function similar to ‘recommendPage’ but did not export the constructor for ‘Blog’ - two options I could think of were adding to the module or utilizing the functions that were exported which is how I came up with this contrived example.

Comment: @SevanGolnazarian I see, that's a fair reason. In that case, though, without knowing which functions the actual module you're talking about exports there's no way to tell what your options are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of caveats. First of all, your `recommendPage` function is unsafe as it fails on empty lists. It is best to avoid functions like `head` and `tail` that are not total and fail on some input. Second, logically, it seems more natural, instead, to have your `recommendNPages` function as the “primary” one, and then implement `recommendPage` as `recommendNPages 1`.

But I am going to assume that you have good reasons to do what you are trying to do exactly this way. Then you could use this straightforward implementation:

```hs
recommendNPages :: Int -> Blog -> ([Post], Blog)
recommendNPages 0 blog = ([], blog)
recommendNPages n blog =
  case recommendPage blog of
    (post, blog') -> case recommendNPages (n - 1) blog' of
      (posts, blog'') -> (post : posts, blog'')
```

However, whenever you see this pattern, you should suspect that a state is involved, which you did, judging by the word “stateful” in the title of the question :).

Indeed, you can view your `recommendPage` function as a stateful computation that “modifies” the blog by extracting one page from it, and then your `recommendNPages` becomes simply this stateful computation repeated `n` times.

The tool that we use in Haskell for this kind of computation is called the [`State` monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#g:2). Combined with the [`replicateM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) function that iterates a monadic computation `n` times, we get:

```hs
recommendNPages :: Int -> Blog -> ([Post], Blog)
recommendNPages n = runState $ replicateM n step
  where
    -- | One step of our computation. (Just wrapping it into `State`.)
    step :: State Blog Post
    step = state recommendPage
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments I've derived a partial answer that doesn't solve the issue with `recommendPage`:

```
recommendNPages :: Int -> Blog -> ([Post], Blog)
recommendNPages 0 b = ([], b)
recommendNPages n b = 
    let (x, b') = recommendPage b in 
        first (x:) $ recommendNPages (n - 1) b'
```

This is using `Data.Bifunctor.first` to map over `[Post]` in the return value of `recommendNPages (n - 1) b'`.